# Extend controller acceleratorservices in Hybris

Tags: controller, sap-commerce-cloud, extend, storefront, accelerator

I have a problem when I try to extends the **SilentOrderPostMockController**. In my storefront extension I create a new controller that extends the other one which belongs to acceleratorservices extension. I add requiered extension in extensioninfo.xml(requires-extension name="acceleratorservices"/
) but trying to make **ant clean all** I get the error that import de.hybris.platform.acceleratorservices.web.payment.controllers.SilentOrderPostMockController cannot be resolved.

I'm using Intellij. Any hint about why this could happen? I'm using Hybris 1905, Thanx a lot.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a TestController, so why you want to use it? You can define your own Controller in your storefront extension. It is important that it has it own URL request mapping but beside that you can copy and paste the logic from the **SilentOrderPostMockController**

Answer (score 0):

You need to copy SilentOrderPostMockControlle with all classes from /web from OOTB. And past it under your custom extension.